# Group data from a dataframe into a separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to group rows in a dataframe on 3 conditions, and take each grouping and create a new dataframe. I am unfamiliar with the groupby function in pandas and all the examples I have come across have been no help. Is groupby the right approach for this kind of solution? or is there a better way to achieve this?

My data looks like this:

```
ID   Date       Product   Type    Cost    Quantity
---- -----      -------   ------  ------  --------
1    1/1/2023   Bike      Buy      10.00    1
2    1/1/2023   Bike      Buy      10.00    1
3    1/1/2023   Bike      Sell     10.00    1
4    1/1/2023   Bike      Sell     10.00    1
5    1/2/2023   Car       Sell     20.00    1
6    1/2/2023   Car       Sell     20.00    1
7    1/3/2023   Truck     Buy      30.00    1
8    1/3/2023   Truck     Buy      30.00    1
```

My expected output needs to be like this, where each data structure holds data with the same products, same type, and on the same date:

```
ID   Date       Product   Type    Cost    Quantity
---- -----      -------   ------  ------  --------
1    1/1/2023   Bike      Buy      10.00    1
2    1/1/2023   Bike      Buy      10.00    1

ID   Date       Product   Type    Cost    Quantity
---- -----      -------   ------  ------  --------
3    1/1/2023   Bike      Sell     10.00    1
4    1/1/2023   Bike      Sell     10.00    1

ID   Date       Product   Type    Cost    Quantity
---- -----      -------   ------  ------  --------
5    1/2/2023   Car       Sell     20.00    1
6    1/2/2023   Car       Sell     20.00    1

ID   Date       Product   Type    Cost    Quantity
---- -----      -------   ------  ------  --------
7    1/3/2023   Truck     Buy      30.00    1
8    1/3/2023   Truck     Buy      30.00    1
```

I am using Python pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose that your data frame is df

###### group by 'Date', 'Product', and 'Type'

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Date', 'Product', 'Type'])
```

###### iterate through the groups and create new DataFrames

```
for name, group in grouped:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(group)
    print(new_df)
    print("\n")
```

### output

```
   ID      Date Product Type  Cost  Quantity
0   1  1/1/2023    Bike  Buy  10.0         1
1   2  1/1/2023    Bike  Buy  10.0         1


   ID      Date Product  Type  Cost  Quantity
2   3  1/1/2023    Bike  Sell  10.0         1
3   4  1/1/2023    Bike  Sell  10.0         1


   ID      Date Product  Type  Cost  Quantity
4   5  1/2/2023     Car  Sell  20.0         1
5   6  1/2/2023     Car  Sell  20.0         1


   ID      Date Product Type  Cost  Quantity
6   7  1/3/2023   Truck  Buy  30.0         1
7   8  1/3/2023   Truck  Buy  30.0         1
```